# Maximum dimension of the socle of a colength n monomial ideal in k[x,y,z]

Tags: co.combinatorics, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be field and fix a positive integer $n$. If $I\subseteq k[x,y,z]$ is a colength-n ideal, what is the maximum possible dimension of the socle of $k[x,y,z]/I$? Is there a formula for this in terms of $n$?

Equivalently, is there a formula for the maximum possible number of corners of a plane partition with $n$ boxes? For example, for $n=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10...$, the maximum possible number of corners is $1,1,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,6,...$ respectively.

Any insight is appreciated!

Comment: If you compute a little further and look into Sloane's integer sequences encyclopaedia (https://oeis.org/), you might find a known sequence. Or maybe you already did?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I had always thought that the OEIS would return all sequences that started with a given input sequence. However, I didn't see it when I inputted only 10 numbers prior to posting (perhaps it prioritized other sequences when I searched?). However, it worked with a few more inputs! The sequence turns out to be A120565 in the OEIS. Thanks again for a helpful comment!

Comment: link: https://oeis.org/search?q=A120565

Comment: Can you explain the equivalence, please?

Comment: @HailongDao The OEIS description says "Maximum over all planar partitions of n of the number of ways the partition can be shrunk by removing a single element." This number of ways a given partition can be shrunk by removing a single element is just a way of saying the number of corners; the maximum over all partitions of $n$ means looking at the partition with the most corners, as the OP asked for; and corners are basis elements for the socle.

Comment: @ZachTeitler: I understand that, but why planar? I thought we are working in 3 variables.

Comment: Ah, never mind, I found the link, interesting: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_partition

Comment: In the same sense that a two dimensional diagram corresponds to an ordinary partition, which is a “1-dimensional list of numbers” in weakly decreasing order, so a 3-d diagram corresponds to a 2-d array of numbers (weakly decreasing in both rows and columns). I assume this is the reason for the name plane partitions for 3-d diagrams. But history is not my forte, perhaps there was originally another reason and this is just rationalization, I don’t know.